# Can I use jquery .each() to calculate each row in a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a form that will calculate the total of each row of an item.

I have used a piece of javascript already to calculate each row individually but i want to know if i can use .each() to calculate every row with the same classes rather than having a piece of script for each row with a unique ID.

The script should be: (the price in the p element with class "price1")*(value in the input element with class "qty1"). The result needs to go into the input element with the class "total1"

My page is http://www.catering-equipment.co.uk/portal1/
I have created a JSFiddle here --> https://jsfiddle.net/1y7kudtv/4/

```
$(".qty1").on('keyup', function () {
    // alert('pressed')
    var total = $(".price1").html() * $(this).val()
    $(".total1").val(total);
})
```

You can see my attempt at the javascript code but it will only work if i use it with unique ID's rather than a class.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.closest()`:

```
$(this).closest('.itemrow').find('.total1').val(total);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/1y7kudtv/8/)

Comment: Hi, this only takes the first instance of .price1 which means, on my example, every row is *2.17

Comment: Just use the same logic? `$(this).closest('.itemrow').find('.price1')` [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/1y7kudtv/11/)

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you so much! Been trying to figure it out for hours! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. Use [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to only look for elements in the current selector:

```
$('.itemrow').each(function() {
    var price = $(this).find('.price1').html();
    var quantity = $(this).find('.qty1').val();

    var total = price * quantity;

    $(this).find('.total1').val(total);
});
```

Also notice that you're dealing with float arithmetics here, so it's better to round the total, to avoid it displaying something like `10.99999999`:

```
var total = (price * quantity).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: I added this and it doesn't calculate live like the on keyup does. How would i implement this?